# Convert a string in char to array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, char

I have a list of strings in a char array:

```
'gvs(0.000000000000000e+000, 1.601985139535780e+002)'
'gvs(-5.000000000000000e-005, 1.365231866954370e+002)'
'gvs(-1.000000000000000e-004, 1.169431404340180e+002)'
'gvs(-5.000000000000000e-004, 3.187711314514890e+001)'
'gvs(-2.000000000000000e-004, 8.589930648472340e+001)'
```

Which I am trying to convert to an array of just the numbers (ignoring gvs, the comma and the brackets), but I can't quite work out what I'm doing wrong?

```
cols = length(Variables) + length(Parameters);
% currently unused
rows = length(Results);

for a = 1:rows;
    Res(a,:) = sscanf ((Results{a,1}(1,:)),'%*s %f %f');
end
```

I've also tried textscan, but I can't get that to work right either

```
for a = 1:rows;
    Res = cell (textscan ((Results{a,1}(1,:)),'%*s %f %f','Delimiter', {'(',' '},'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1));
end
```

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: The problem here is that `%*s` reads characters until the first whitespace. What you need is to explicitly match the `gvs` string (including the parentheses). Also, there's really no point for the `(1, :)` indexing, just use `Results{a, 1}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
Res(a,:) = sscanf ((Results{a,1}(1,:)),'%*s %f %f');
```

with

```
Res(a,:) = sscanf ((Results{a,1}(1,:)),'gvs(%f, %f)');
```

Comment: When I do that I get "Conversion to cell from double is not possible." error?  If I remove the (a,:) after Res, then I get: 

Res =

   -0.0002
   85.8993

Which seems to be getting there, but only the last row...

Comment: Ah, I fixed it

Res{a,1} = sscanf ((Results{a,1}),'gvs(%f, %f)')';

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a **char** array (not a cellstring):

```
s = ['gvs( 0.000000000000000e+000, 1.601985139535780e+002)'
     'gvs(-5.000000000000000e-005, 1.365231866954370e+002)'
     'gvs(-1.000000000000000e-004, 1.169431404340180e+002)'
     'gvs(-5.000000000000000e-004, 3.187711314514890e+001)'
     'gvs(-2.000000000000000e-004, 8.589930648472340e+001)']
```

Then you can simply `textscan()`:

```
data = textscan(s','gvs(%f%f)','CollectOutput',1,'Delimiter',',');
data = data{1}
data =
         0  160.1985
   -0.0001  136.5232
   -0.0001  116.9431
   -0.0005   31.8771
   -0.0002   85.8993
```

If `s` is a **cellstring**, then before calling textscan, convert to `char()`:

```
s = char(s);
```

Comment: I think `Results` is a cell array, note the curly braces in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your string is almost in MATLAB-array compatible format, you could commit a sin and use `evalc`:

```
>> s = {
    'gvs( 0.000000000000000e+000, 1.601985139535780e+002)'
    'gvs(-5.000000000000000e-005, 1.365231866954370e+002)'
    'gvs(-1.000000000000000e-004, 1.169431404340180e+002)'
    'gvs(-5.000000000000000e-004, 3.187711314514890e+001)'
    'gvs(-2.000000000000000e-004, 8.589930648472340e+001)'};

>> C = evalc(['[' regexprep([s{:}], {'gvs\(' '\)'}, {'' ';'}) ']'])

ans =
                         0    1.601985139535780e+002
   -5.000000000000000e-005    1.365231866954370e+002
   -1.000000000000000e-004    1.169431404340180e+002
   -5.000000000000000e-004    3.187711314514890e+001
   -2.000000000000000e-004    8.589930648472340e+001
```